# Segmentation Fault on map inside structure

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct

> I am creating a structure which contains map
>   but when I try to insert an element , It throws segmentation fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
typedef struct a
{
    map<int,int> m;
}a;
int main()
{
    a* b;
    b=(a*) malloc(sizeof(a));
    b->m[0]=0;

 }
```

Answer (score 7):

None of your code even starts to resemble idiomatic C++, the best thing anyone can recommend to you is to pick up a good book about C++.

A quick fix for your program: Use `new` instead of `malloc` - `malloc` doesn't belong in C++ code. That will make sure that `a->m` is actually constructed. Then, be sure to delete `b` at the end. This comes with all the problems of `new/delete`, so when you know a little more about the basics of C++, read up on smart pointers.

A slightly more drastic change, that will result in less problems in your simple program: Use automatic storage:

```
a b;
b.m[0] = 0;
```

This would be your program in C++ rather than the weird C/C++ mix:

```
#include<map>

struct a
{
    std::map<int,int> m;
};

int main()
{
    a b;
    b.m[0]=0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for recommending operator new.
Code pasted above is just a sample code.In the real code, I need .
a *b  rather a b;

Answer (score 2):

Use the `new` operator to dynamically allocate memory otherwise the map's constructor within the struct will not be invoked when using `malloc`.

```
int main()
{
    a* b;
    b= new a;

    b->m[0]=0;
    // Do whatever here

    // When you're done using the variable b
    // free up the memory you had previously allocated
    // by invoking delete
    delete b;

    return 0;
}
```